# Mesh Filter Cosmetic Damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, mesh, destroy

Presently trying to work on a script that allows a ball to take cosmetic mesh damage as it goes through a level. Problem is, Ive been having trouble finding the proper equation for moving the vertexs.

Heres what I have thusfar

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshDenter : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3[] originalMesh;
    public float dentFactor;
    public LayerMask collisionMask;
    private MeshFilter meshFilter;
    void Start() {
        meshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        originalMesh = meshFilter.mesh.vertices;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        Vector3[] meshCoordinates = originalMesh;
        // Loop through collision points
        foreach (ContactPoint point in collision.contacts) {
            // Index with the closest distance to point.
            int lastIndex = 0;
            // Loop through mesh coordinates
            for (int i = 0; i < meshCoordinates.Length; i++) {
                // Check to see if there is a closer index
                if (Vector3.Distance(point.point, meshCoordinates[i])
                    < Vector3.Distance(point.point, meshCoordinates[lastIndex])) {
                    // Set the new index
                    lastIndex = i;
                }
            }
            // Move the vertex
            meshCoordinates[lastIndex] += /*Insert Rest Of Equation Here*/;
        }
        meshFilter.mesh.vertices = meshCoordinates;
    }

    void Reset() {
        meshFilter.mesh.vertices = originalMesh;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might check the parameters to that `Reflect` call. Is the game 2D or 3D in nature? If your movement is primarily 2D, the corresponding `collision.relativeVelocity` will tend to limit your output.

Comment: This script manipulates 3D mesh. The gameplay itself is 2D-ish http://gyazo.com/96f472dc6bfcbc8893290ccf6b4c16e6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/962794/mesh-collision-damage.html#answer-966389

> I would suggest two options:
>
> Use a random deformation like:
>
> ```
> meshCoordinates[lastIndex] += new Vector3(Random.Range(-DeformScale,DeformScale),
> ```
>
> Random.Range(-DeformScale,DeformScale),
>   Random.Range(-DeformScale,DeformScale));
>
> Dent inwards by offsetting the vertex by the inverse normal like:
>
> ```
> meshCoordinates[lastIndex] -= meshCoordinates[lastIndex].normalized * DeformScale;
> ```